# AWS EB command to create environment without scaling/single instance

Tags: command-line, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We currently can call `eb create` to create and deploy our app onto AWS Elastic Beanstalk hosting.

My need is to have the same outcome with **no scaling** i.e. single instance mode.

What is the command syntax for that?

Answer (score 0):

I try

```
eb create --help
```

and find -s --single param to get it single.

[image]